React CDN Pivottable Uncaught ReferenceError
I am trying to use CDN to do a simple pivot table using the react-pivottable library.
Here is the HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React PivotTable Example</title>

    <!-- React and ReactDOM CDN links -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Babel CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!--react-pivottable-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-pivottable@0.11.0/PlotlyRenderers.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-pivottable@0.11.0/pivottable.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- Your React app script -->
<script src="JS/report/ReactPivotTest.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>


and here is the react code:
const e = React.createElement;

const data = [['attribute', 'attribute2'], ['value1', 'value2']];

class ReactPivotTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = props;
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <PivotTableUI
            data={data}
            onChange={s => this.setState(s)}
            {...this.state}
            />
            );
        }
    }
    
    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
    root.render(e(ReactPivotTest));

When the page loads up I get:
Uncaught ReferenceError: PivotTableUI is not defined
The example is from the CDN site:
text
